# How to join this two sql to be show in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT AA, AB, AC, AD, AE
FROM Table1 WHERE AA<'5'
ORDER BY AA ASC, AB DESC


SELECT BA, BB
FROM Table2
WHERE BA <6 ORDER BY BA DESC;
```

The output should be like below picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ac5E.png)

Comment: You can start by telling us which column(s) should be used in the join.

Comment: For us to be able to help, we need to know what your final desired result should be. As Tim has stated, what columns do you want to see. Give us the WHAT, and we might be able to help with the HOW

Comment: here the link that show the output should be show in one table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ac5E.png

Comment: In your query you have `BA < 6`. In your image you have `BA = `Caption 5'`. So is `BA` a number or a string now?

Comment: Rather then linking to an image, you should have pasted the data as text. Not everybody is allowed to download images.

Comment: Noted Thorsten Kettne

Answer (score 0):

as on your png file you should join on BB=AB for this use below query

```
Select BA,BB as `BB=AB`,AC,AD,AE from Table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.BB=t2.AB 
where t1.BA <6 and t2.AA<'5'
ORDER BY BA DESC, AA ASC, AB DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When joining two queries we must use parentheses around them and give them names (`a` and `b` in below query):

```
select b.ba, a.aa, a.ab, a.ac, a.ad
from (select aa, ab, ac, ad, ae from table1 where aa < '5') a
join (select ba, bb from table2 where ba < 6) b on b.bb = a.ab
order by b.ba desc;
```